# Issue setting FlushMode.COMMIT in Quarkus Hibernate ORM

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, quarkus

Issue I have using Quarkus+Hibernate:
For performance purposes we need to set FlushMode as COMMIT in our hibernate Session.
And we realized that this property configuration is not available in application.properties parameters, see: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#hibernate-configuration-properties

So, we took the path to setting up the configuration with **persistence.xml** file: https://quarkus.io/guides/hibernate-orm#persistence-xml

```
...
    <persistence-unit name="SomethingPU"    transaction-type="JTA">
        <description>Something Entities</description>
        <properties>
            <!-- Connection specific -->
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect" />
            
            <!-- cache properties -->
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_minimal_puts" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>
            
            <!-- multitenancy -->
            <property name="hibernate.multiTenancy" value="DATABASE" />
                
            <!-- scan for annotated classes -->
                   <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class"/>
            
            <!-- performance tunning -->
            <property name="org.hibernate.flushMode" value="COMMIT" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.batch_size" value="100" />
            <property name="hibernate.jdbc.fetch_size" value="400" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_updates" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.order_inserts" value="true" />
            <property name="hibernate.max_fetch_depth" value="1" />
            
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
```

When we start our service everything's fine, the properties are loaded into the Session, except for "org.hibernate.flushMode" parameter.
Debugging the code we see this behaviour:

- when the service starts, Quarkus executes the Recorder: io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.HibernateOrmRecorder
- this class initialize org.hibernate.Session using the class: io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.TransactionSessions
- TransactionsSessions mantains a Map of io.quarkus.hibernate.orm.runtime.session.TransactionScopedSession
- so, when TransactionScopedSession acquires the Session, it executes:

TransactionScopedSession.aquireSession
line 88:
 `Session newSession = jtaSessionOpener.openSession();`

which ends calling JTASessionOpener.createOptions method:

```
return sessionFactory.withOptions()
                .autoClose(true) // .owner() is deprecated as well, so it looks like we need to rely on deprecated code...
                .connectionHandlingMode(
                        PhysicalConnectionHandlingMode.DELAYED_ACQUISITION_AND_RELEASE_BEFORE_TRANSACTION_COMPLETION)
                .flushMode(FlushMode.ALWAYS);
```

Here JTASessionOpener is setting flushMode as ALWAYS
calling the method: `SessionFactoryImpl.flushMode`

When org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl is created
org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.SessionImpl(SessionFactoryImpl, SessionCreationOptions)
line 266:

```
if ( getHibernateFlushMode() == null ) {
    final FlushMode initialMode;
    if ( this.properties == null ) {
        initialMode = fastSessionServices.initialSessionFlushMode;
    }
...
```

The method getHibernateFlushMode() is returning FlushMode.ALWAYS
And because of this, the parameter "org.hibernate.flushMode" from persistence.xml is never setted.

---

We fix this issue setting the flushMode directly in javax.persistence.EntityManager instance, before we use it in any query or DB operation.

But, my questions are:

1. is there a way to bypass JTASessionOpener or use another logic? can it be considered as a bug or issue to solve?
2. is there a better way (than our solution) to fix this issue?
3. is there a plan to add the property "org.hibernate.flushMode" in Quarkus Hibernate ORM extension?, so we can set this in application.properties
   --

Hope the description is clear.